# Automatic line changing in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++

When I'm typing in Notepad++ the line trails endlessly. I'm trying to make it automatically go to the next line once I reach the end of the line instead of continuously going. Is this possible? I used to be able to do it on my other OS but now I'm stuck. I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit. I'm also using the latest version of Notepad++ (5.9.1).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to enable "Word wrap" via the "View" menu. This setting affects all open documents.